# Pandoc, how to allow right tab-stop when converting a .docx exported from Google Doc to .latex

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, pandoc

Google Docs and Drive, OpenOffice and Microsoft word all have the right tab-stop functionality

[image: docx view]

This is how you configure it in Google Document:

- Type the text you want on the left
- Click the ruler & "Add right tab-stop"
- Press "Tab"
- Type text you want to be right-aligned
- Adjust the right tab stop to line up with margin (they are 2 different things)

It’s not obvious, but then it works great.

I use `TAB` + a number to write how long day the task will take.

Now I want to convert it to `.pdf` with LaTeX and Pandoc, this is the latex document after being converted:

[image: LaTeX view]

I have looked at a generated `.tex` file. This one is produced by a non OpenSource script and they render it right while I don't, this is the difference:

`.tex` valid result:

```
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\section*{Task big title\hspace*{10pt}2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Task big title\hspace*{10pt}2}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
Description task \tabto{6.29in} 2\par
```

This is what I have in my generated `.tex` (wrong result):

```
\section{Task big title 2}\label{task-big-title-2}

Description task 2
```

With pandoc, I am able to edit the generated file with:

- include in header with `--include-in-header`: Include contents of FILE, verbatim, at the end of the header.
- include before body with `--include-before-body`: Include contents of FILE, verbatim, at the beggining of the document body.
- include after body with `--include-after-body`: Include contents of FILE, verbatim, at the end of the document body.
- the whole template used for generating the latex document with `--latex`. ([See default template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex))

How can I preserve the formatting of the right-tab stop when converting a `.docx` **exported with Google doc** document to `.pdf` latex documents using **pandoc**?

Comment: Use `\rightskip`.  While lists often recompute `\leftskip` using `\@totalleftmargin` they usually leave `\rightskip` alone.  Exceptions are things like quote or center.

Comment: I have tried to activate `--preserve-tabs` options in pandoc but that doesn't add `\rightskip` to the produced tex. I am trying to convert a .docx exported from Google Document to .pdf

Comment: Pandoc isn't the right tool for preserving formatting. Still, you could try your luck, writing a filter...